# Export html data / json data to excel sheet using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I need to export the json data or html data to excel sheet using html and jquery ( no server code). I have searched for it and got some of the fiddles where i can able to download the excel sheet successfully. But none of them are working in Internet explorer.

```
{http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/xhYcD/}
{http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/wVejP/}
```

My requirement is to export the json/html data to excel sheet using pure html and jquery and should work in all browsers. I have been searching for it but didn't find the appropriate solution. Can you guys help me in this regard. If you provide any workaround or link which satisfies my requirement , that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"none of them are working in Internet explorer"* What is the problem?  What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Here is the js [link]http://jsfiddle.net/cebJN/ @Archer. This code is working fine in firefox and chrome but not in IE. I have searched for the solution and I got some info saying the following code should be added in server side. `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfilename.csv");` . Since am using only jquery and no server side, i am unable to get how to handle this. Please let me know where am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: You still haven't explained what actually happens though.  "It doesn't work" is not an explanation.  Is there any error information in the console?  Is it the xls creation or the download that's failing?  More info is needed if you want any help :)

Comment: just opening the new tab when I click on Export button in IE. No errors in console even. I decided to navigate to the new aspx page when user clicks on Export Excel button. So that I can write the server code there to make the excel download in all browsers. I found solution like adding `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfilename.csv");` in server event to make the excel download in IE. As am a fresher i don't know in which event i should keep this line.Please help me

Answer (score 1):

IE has restrictions on using "data" URI's - you should read up on those first.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx

Specifically, only these uses are supported:

```
"- object (images only) 
- img 
- input type=image 
- link 
- CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background, backgroundImage, and so on."
```